# C# socket problems

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I connected to PCs with a cable in an attempt to simulate server\client. Server starts listening at specific EndPoint and sometimes later a client connects. All went well and I settled on maximum speed of about 24 Mbps for one connection (port).
So now I reversed the roles and can't get connection `Socket.BeginConnect(ServerEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnectCallback), _ClientSocket)` times out and sets localEndpoint to 0.0.0.0

Here is the code for client:

```
public void ConnectToServer(IPAddress iPAddress, int Port)
    {
        connected.Reset();
        IPEndPoint ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(iPAddress, Port);

        try
        {
            _ClientSocket = new Socket(iPAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _ClientSocket.BeginConnect(ServerEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnectCallback), _ClientSocket);

            connected.WaitOne();

            // Here I would like to start async receiving but there's no connection
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            // TODO:
        }
    }

private void OnConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client_StateSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;

            client_StateSocket.EndConnect(result);

            /// Here I get 0.0.0.0
            connected.Set();
        }

        catch (SocketException)
        {
            // TODO:
        }
    }
```

The server is bascialy from MSDN example. It starts listening for incoming connections, goes in perpetual `while` cycle and sits waiting for `Socket.BeginAccept` to trigger (but it never does).
I suspected firewall, but the settings look the same on both PCs and works fine in reversed way, so what might be the problem?

Comment: You can't have both the client and listen have the save three properties 1) Source IP  2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  So when client and server are on the same machine you MUST have server listen on IP.Any.   Then have client connect to IP address of machine (or machine name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do development of a Server/Client architecture, it is usually enough to have both run on the same machine and let them talk via the Loopback IP adress. As a general rule the networking code does not care if the other end is on the same computer, the same switch - or the Voyager 2 probe (well, they do care a little as the Latency is quite high).

If you are having issues in deployment/testing, then with 99% propability you are dealing with a **Networking** problem, not a programming one. Sometimes there will be some required changes (like exposing the option to set proxy settings). But debugging will be a Networking operation first.

My first guesses are towards firewalls (including the one built into Windows). And then things that work similar to a firewall, like NAT layers.

Comment: What is the best way to solve it? Pinging works and PC can successfully send data when working as a server. But when it acts as a client it seems like it doesn't even start the connection. I found recommendations on using wireshark or something similar but I have no experience with it. Built in Windows performance monitor just shows it in TCP-connections in grey

Comment: @Leinad: either it is a firewall getting in the way (possibly one sided proxy setting). Or there is a layer of NAT between the two machines. NAT (like the one you find in your Router) allow answers to a request to be received - while ignoring all unexpected traffic. Making a webserver that is reachable from the Internet is mostly about getting around NAT.

Comment: PCs are connected directly via Ethernet cable and I can ping each of them from console with their specified IPs. Normally (as far as I saw) local port is @Christopher: selected automatically when connecting to RemoteEndpoint. I tried binding it but still no use. On both PCs' firewalls server and client apps have full permission. Is it a problem with sending request (from PC) or allowing it (on laptop)?

Comment: @Leinad unfortunately there are too many possible causes of this. It could even be something like a missing pre-requisite for the server on one machine. Your exception handling might actually get in the way of getting the information, by swallowing the problem. My best advice is to remove them or fill them with a simple `throw;` order so you actually see something.